# How to sum all elements in an indexed table

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to make a query to my database with this structure: [Data Base Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUJln.png)

I did this query:

```
SELECT partido.acronimoPartido, SUM(votosacta.numVotos) FROM partido, votosacta WHERE votosacta.partido_idpartido=1 AND partido.idpartido=1
```

This query does work like I want but displays only the SUM of 'votos' for idpartido=1

I want to be able to sum numVotos from 'votosacta' table for each member of my 'partido' table indexed in 'votosacta' but I seem to not be able to get the right sintax.
I tried something like this:

```
SELECT partido.acronimoPartido, SUM(votosacta.numVotos) FROM partido, votosacta WHERE votosacta.partido_idpartido = partido.idpartido
```

Comment: You are missing a GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a group by clause:

```
select p.acronimoPartido,
    SUM(v.numVotos)
from partido p
join votosacta v on v.partido_idpartido = p.idpartido
group by p.acronimoPartido
```

Also, use *explicit* join syntax instead of old comma based syntax and use aliases to make your queries concise and readable.